How to Change Magento 2 Mobile Menu Behavior to Accordion Style
I am working on a Magento 2 project, and currently, the mobile menu opens categories in a new tab when clicked. This behavior isn't ideal, and I want to change it so that the submenu expands and collapses using an accordion style instead.
Current Behavior:

Clicking any category opens it in a new tab.

the new tab open.


Desired Behavior:

Clicking a category expands its submenu using an accordion style.

I have reviewed the Magento 2 theme files and suspect that changes are needed in the menu's JavaScript or CSS, but I am unsure how to proceed or where exactly to make the changes.
Environment:

Magento 2.x


You should look at this  2 files
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/menu.js
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/jquery/ui-modules/widgets/menu.js


extend
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/jquery/ui-modules/widgets/menu.js

and change the behavior  of the  dropdown, I think it would  be good to use this  in your require-config.js file and  play with options

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
